# sprintf in php, format string which has percent signs in it

Tags: php

How can i go about situation when i have % marks in my string, and I also want to use placeholders. Sprintf() treat all % marks as a placeholders and therefore throws an error that not each placeholder matches with given parameters?

```
sprintf(
        'SELECT formatDateTime(toDateTime(date_time), \'%Y%m%d\') as Ymd, count(tr_cars)
        FROM hours_data
        WHERE  (date_time BETWEEN \'%s\' AND \'%s\') AND station_id = %d
        GROUP BY Ymd',
        $args['dateFrom'],
        $args['dateTo'],
        $root['stationId']
    )
);
```

IDE prompt: Conversion specification is not mapped to any parameter.

php output: "debugMessage":

> "sprintf(): Too few arguments"

Comment: Since it's a database query, you should rather use prepared statements with placeholders than inserting data into your queries like that.

Answer (score 3):

If you need to escape a `%` symbol, you simply put two of them together `%%`:

```
$var = 'Awesome';
sprintf( 'This string is 100%% %s!', $var ); // Output: This string is 100% Awesome!
```

@Magnus Eriksson is correct though. In this particular instance, you'll want to use [Prepared Statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) if this is an actual query you're going to run on your database.